# Calculating if the text will take more than one line inside onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, textview

I've got a text of an undetermined length and a `TextView` with         `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. Inside my `RecyclerView.Adapter` `onBindViewHolder` I need to calculate whether the given text will fit into the given `TextView` as a single line, or whether more than one line is needed (in which case I have the requirement to change the UI).

I know how to figure out the text width:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    HeaderViewHolder holder = (HeaderViewHolder) viewHolder;
    String text = mSelectedItem.getText();

    Paint paint = holder.textview.getPaint();
    Rect bounds = new Rect();

    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
    Log.d(TAG,"bounds w: "+bounds.width());
    Log.d(TAG,"bounds h: "+bounds.height());
}
```

However, I'm not sure what would be an efficient way forward from this. The text height is not of much use to me here as the bounds will only show the height of a single line of text.

I was thinking of measuring the width of the TextView's parent element and compare if the text width is larger than the parent width:

```
    View v = (View) holder.textview.getParent();
    v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    Log.e(TAG,"parent width "+v.getMeasuredWidth());
```

However, that returns a weird result of 522 when my whole layout hierarchy has the width set to `match_parent` and I'm testing on Nexus 5, so the value should be around 1080. The same value I get if I attempt to measure my `RecyclerView`. Also I think that's inefficient as it calls for an extra measurement cycle.

I've also tried:

```
    ViewGroup parentView = ((ViewGroup) holder.textview.getParent());
    double parentWidth = parentView.getWidth() - parentView.getPaddingLeft() - parentView
            .getPaddingRight();
```

which works ok, but only after the first pass, which is obviously not good enough.

Any suggestions on a better way of determining whether the given text will fit a single line of the TextView?

**EDIT:**

Updated the code snippet

Comment: You need to check out the `android.text.Layout` subclasses `BoringLayout` and `StaticLayout`.  One of these should help you

Comment: cool, thanks for the tip. will have a look

Comment: looks like I can use the StaticLayout to figure out the height of my text, but again, I need to know the width of the bounds, which I don't.. Back to square one... Actually if I knew the width I wouldn't need the layout at all, cause I could just compare the text bounds width with the parent width.

Comment: Your code snippets are short, so I don't know where in the lifecycle you are measuring.  Are you overriding `onMeasure` or `onLayout` in a custom `TextView`?  Are you using a `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` to get the layout event?

Comment: It's inside onBindViewHolder in the adapter. Not using global listener, would prefer to avoid it.

Comment: @krislarson I've updated the questions with more details, in case you'll have a chance to have another look. Thanks